# Flask Exception Handling and Message Flashing

Tags: python, flask, exception, jinja2

I have python code that registers an error in the console when certain conditions are not met. I'm trying to get those same errors visible in the browser when the conditions necessary are not satisfied. To illustrate, consider the very basic idea in the function `add_stuff` which checks to see that the inputs are of type `int`. If not, an error is printed to screen.

The following simple flask app and corresponding template file work, and the value error is in fact printed on screen. But, I am trying to "pretty print" the error, such that it doesn't print the ugly jinga2 error page, but instead stays on the same `math.html` page with the error printed to screen or possible redirects to an attractive page that is not crowded with tracebacks etc.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, current_app
server = Flask(__name__)

def add_stuff(x,y):
    if isinstance(x, int) and isinstance(y, int):
        z = x + y
        return z
    else:
        raise ValueError("Not integers")       


@server.route('/math')
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 15
    out = add_stuff(a,b)
    return render_template('math.html', out=out)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

Here's a template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

{{out}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the exception of `add_stuff` method to stop displaying `jinja2` error page.

Here, I have included the exception message in `flash` and have displayed it in the template. If there is an exception, I do not display `out` value in the template.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
     request, url_for

server = Flask(__name__)
server.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'


def add_stuff(x,y):
    if isinstance(x, int) and isinstance(y, int):
        z = x + y
        return z
    else:
        raise ValueError("Not integers")       


@server.route('/math')
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = "some string"
    out = None
    try:
        out = add_stuff(a,b)
    except Exception as e:
        flash(str(e))
    if out is not None:
        return render_template('math.html', out=out)
    else:
        return render_template('math.html')
```

`math.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

{% if out %}
    {{out}}
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output of flash]

You can also categorize `flash` messages as per requirements(e.g.: error, warning, etc.). You can read [the official documentation here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/).